# cannot use keybinding for move-to-workspace-9/10 with parentleft/parentright

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, workspaces

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Gnome 3.36.8

tried:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-9 "[\"<Shift><Super>parenleft\"]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-10 "[\"<Shift><Super>parenright\"]"
```

**but it doesnt work**.
I got these names from:

```
xmodmap -pk     
and 
xev
```

other keys for for workspace-10 like 'braceright' do work and also the rest:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-1 ['<Shift><Super>exclam']
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-2 ['<Shift><Super>at']
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-3 ['<Shift><Super>numbersign']
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-5 "[\"<Shift><Super>percent"]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-6 "[\"<Shift><Super>asciicircum\"]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-7 "[\"<Shift><Super>ampersand\"]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-8 "[\"<Shift><Super>asterisk\"]"
```

I could not find out what is the problem. I use switch to workflow 1->0 and I would like to use them also for moving windows.

Answer (score 0):

for some reason even when 'shift' is involved still have to use numbers here:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-9 "[\"<Shift><Super>9\"]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-10 "[\"<Shift><Super>0\"]"
```

but for number '2':

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-2 ['<Shift><Super>at']
```

for switch-to-workspace-2  I have the:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-2 ['<Super>2']
```